# How do I select multiple instances which fulfill the WHERE clause?

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have a database which has the names of all the ships.
If I wish to select all the ships which have minimum of 10 guns, I'd do.

```
SELECT Class AS Class,Country.
FROM Classes
WHERE numGuns >=10;
```

However, I wish to select all ships and print them out who have `numGuns >= 10`, I've tried googling myself out of this however I haven't found something simple to work with and work from there.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I wish to select all ships and print them out who have numGuns >= 10"... how is that different from the query you already wrote?

Comment: Are the ships stored in the `Classes` table?

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's just me being a flool.

Answer (score 0):

*This is just to get the question out of the list of unanswered questions

(and close-voting did not help).*

The problem is caused by the simple mistake of trying to list the ship attributes "class" and "country", according to the attribute "numGuns" from a class table (which at least does not have all of these attributes) instead of from a ship table (where they exist).